# Storing objects in a vector, compiler says an element does not exist

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector

I'm practicing with classes and vectors and storing objects in vectors. After storing a base class object and a class object that inherits from it, my compiler returns the error that the inherited class object does not exist. Here are what I assume are the important bits:

*The Car class and the Sportscar class, which inherits from Car*

```
class Car
{
    public:
        Car();
        void stop();
        int get_speed() const;
        void new_speed(int fspeed);

    protected:
        int speed;
};

class Sportscar : public Car
{
    public:
        Sportscar();
        void turbo();

    private:
        bool hasTurbo;
};
```

*Storing the objects in the vector cars:*

```
vector<Car*> cars(2);

    cars[0] = new Car();
    cars[1] = new Sportscar();
```

*A case of accessing `cars[0]` and `cars[1]` where `cars[0]` is accessed fine, but `cars[1]` is not:*

```
cars[1]->turbo();
cars[0]->new_speed(cars[0]->get_speed());
```

Here is the full code, which is a bit all over the place since I wasn't sure initially where I was going with this little car game:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
    public:
        Car();
        void stop();
        int get_speed() const;
        void new_speed(int fspeed);

    protected:
        int speed;
};

class Sportscar : public Car
{
    public:
        Sportscar();
        void turbo();

    private:
        bool hasTurbo;
};

// Constructor for class Car
Car::Car()
{
    speed = 1;
}

// Function to stop the car
void Car::stop()
{
    speed = 0;

    cout << "You stop the car.\n" << endl;
}

// Function to get current speed of the car
int Car::get_speed() const
{
    return speed;
}

// Function to "accelerate" the car
void Car::new_speed(int fspeed)
{
    int newspeed;

    cout << "Speed up by how many mp/h? ";
    cin >> newspeed;

    speed = (fspeed + newspeed);

    cout << "You speed up.\n" << endl;
}

// Sportscar constructor to set hasTurbo to 0 (no)
Sportscar::Sportscar()
    // Not sure if this is necessary
    : Car()
{
    hasTurbo = 0;
}

// Function to designate if the car has turbo
void Sportscar::turbo()
{
    hasTurbo = 1;

    cout << "You have activated turbo and have greater acceleration.\n" << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<Car*> cars(2);

    cars[0] = new Car();
    cars[1] = new Sportscar();

    //Car drive;
    //Sportscar drivefast;
    char ans;
    char sport;

    // Asks user for input A, B, C, or Q until user chooses Q to quit
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Enter 'A' for current speed, 'B' to speed up, or 'C' to stop. 'Q' to quit." << endl;
        cin >> ans;

        // If users chooses A, calls get_speed() function and outputs current speed
        if (ans == 'A')
        {
            cout << "Your current speed is " << cars[0]->get_speed() << " mp/h.\n" << endl;
        }

        // If user chooses B, calls new_speed() function to increase speed according to
        // user's specifications
        else if (ans == 'B')
        {
            // Asks user if they have turbo Y/N
            cout << "Do you want to use turbo? Y/N: ";
            cin >> sport;

            // If user does have turbo, hasTurbo is set to 1 (yes) and function
            // new_speed() is called
            if (sport == 'Y')
            {
                cars[1]->turbo();
                cars[0]->new_speed(cars[0]->get_speed());
            }

            // If user does not have turbo, hasTurbo stays at 0 (no) and function
            // new_speed() is called
            else if (sport == 'N')
            {
                cars[0]->new_speed(cars[0]->get_speed());
            }

            // If user answers other can Y or N, tells user input is incorrect
            else
            {
                cout << "Incorrect input.\n" << endl;
            }
        }

        // If user chooses C, calls stop() function and reduces car's speed to 0
        else if (ans == 'C')
        {
            cars[0]->stop();
        }

        // If user chooses Q, program ends
        else if (ans == 'Q')
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        // If user chooses other than A, B, C, or Q, tells user input is incorrect
        else
        {
            cout << "Incorrect input.\n" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my compiler error:

[image]

I should note that if I remove the line accessing `cars[1]`, the program compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector is declared as a vector of `Car*` types. An object of type `Car` does not have a `turbo` member function. You need to cast the pointer to a `Sportscar*` type:

```
static_cast<Sportscar*>(cars[1])->turbo();
```

Comment: Note, this causes undefined behaviour if `cars[1]` were not actually a `Sportscar`. Also it will cause UB to `delete cars[1]` without repeating the static_cast. Making `Car` polymorphic is probably the best cause of action.

Answer (score 0):

`cars` is `vector<Car*>`, and `Car` indeed does not have a `turbo()` member function.

C++ uses static name lookup. It's not going to Look at a `Car*`, see that at runtime it points to a `Sportscar` and then lookup `turbo` in `Sportscar`.

If you want that dynamic behavior then you've got to write it yourself (after fixing your base class to actually support polymorphism):

```
if (auto sc = dynamic_cast<Sportscar*>(cars[1])) {
  sc->turbo();
} else {
  std::cout << "cars[1] is not a Sportscar\n";
}
```

(of course since you know it's a Sportscar you could unconditionally `static_cast` it as well)

---

The dynamic behavior you can get is for virtual methods: A base class declares some 'interface' via virtual methods, and then you can use those virtual methods on classes of that base type. At runtime, if the class is really a derived type then the derived method is called.

```
struct Base {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
  virtual void foo() override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Base *b = new Derived;
  b->foo(); // prints "Derived"
}
```

Calling `foo` on `b` is only allowed because, at compile time, the compiler can see that `Base` has a method `foo`, but since the method is virtual the compiler also sets up machinery so that the actual method implementation that's called at runtime is determined at runtime by the actual type of the object. But in order to set this up the compiler has to see that `foo` is a virtual function without knowing anything about `Derived`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` only works on polymorphic classes; `Car` needs to have a virtual function (preferably the destructor) for that cast to work.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, that's true. I hadn't noticed it wasn't already.

Answer (score 0):

When your SportsCar class inherits from Car, you can add methods just fine. When you store a SportsCar in a vector, it still keeps all the SportsCar data, but you can't access it because it is being considered as a Car ONLY. if you want to access the "turbo()" method, you have to cast the object "cars[1]" to a SportsCar.

```
SportsCar mySportsCar = (SportsCar)cars[1];
//Now you can call .turbo() on mySportsCar

//You could also do it in one line, like so :
((SportsCar)cars[1]).turbo();
```

One thing you have to keep in mind, not ever object in your vector is a SportsCar, and therefor you have to check the type before casting them, or you will get an exception thrown. There's multiple ways to do that, here's one :

```
if(SportsCar *mySportsCar = dynamic_cast<SportsCar*>(&cars[0]))
{
    //Your car was successfully casted, you can use it here
}
else
{
    //Your car is not a SportsCar
}
```

Comment: downvoted for using C-style casts; will update if you rewrite to use C++ casts.  (There are actually some corner cases where C style casts are required in C++ but this is not one of them). Also, `dynamic_cast` only works if the base has a virtual function.